# Where has ImportErrors table gone when importing Excel file into Access?

Tags: excel, ms-access-2007

I'm trying to import a large Excel 2007 file into Access 2007 but it fails with:

> MS Access was unable to append all the data into the table. The
>   contents of 43147 record(s) were deleted, and 0 record(s) were lost
>   due to violations. Do you want to proceed?

When I had this problem before, Access had produce an `ImportErrors` table that showed the field and row number in which each rejected data value was located. I could then go back and look at the Excel table and work out what the problem was.

This time around, the records are imported into the Access table, but I don't get any `ImportErrors` table.

Can anyone tell me how to find it, or make Access produce it, please?